# Apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk fails

Tags: java, linux, docker, apt-get, apt

When installing **openjdk-8-jdk** through **apt** on **DockerFile** and **Linux** node running with **Jenkins** I get the following message:

> The command `apt-get update && apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk` returned a non-zero code: 100.

Full log:

> Step 5/7 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk
>    ---> Running in ...
>
> ...
>
> Err:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release
>     Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/deb.debian.org_debian_dists_stretch_Release - open (28: No space left on device)
>
> Err:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates Release
>     Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/deb.debian.org_debian_dists_stretch-updates_Release - open (28: No space left on device)
>
> Err:6 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates Release
>     Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.debian.org_debian-security_dists_stretch_updates_Release - open (28: No space left on device)
>   Reading package lists...

What can I do to solve this issue?

Comment: try running `apt-transport-https` before update

Comment: are you  trying to install in Ubuntu ? If yes which version of ubuntu ?

Comment: Try running the _update_ and _install_ commands separately. Right now, we don't know which one is failing

Comment: Also, you might have better luck at https://askubuntu.com/ (the Ubuntu-specific StackExchange site)

Comment: Is there any log/output to share?

Comment: Thank you all for the answers. I have updated the question with the details you asked for. For now I could solve the issue with `docker system prune`. Probably this is not even related with apt but not enough space on device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I found to this problem was to clear the space after every build. Clearing the space on the device manually with `docker system prune` wasn't the perfect solution since after some builds you had to keep cleaning it.

```
pipeline {
    stages {
        stage ('start') {
            ...
        }
     }

     post {
        always {
            sh "docker system prune -f"
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have space left on device. Clear space and try again

Comment: Can you recommend a solution to have the device always clean?
For instance, run `docker system prune` after build completes?

Comment: You mist clear unused images if there are many. Or check for logs which are filling your disk. If container space is getting filled,  you may want to set limits as per requirement or you xan try multistage builds if something is needed just once in container. Youy accept the answer if this was your issue.